# How to select all the first td's in a table

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Hi I would like to select only the first `<td>` (`td` with the text *"label"*) of every row in a table, if you have a simple html like:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>label</td> <td>value</td></tr>
  <tr><td>label</td> <td>value</td></tr>
  <tr><td>label</td> <td>value</td></tr>
</table>
```

I would like to assign for example a width of 10% only to the first `<td></td>` group with selector I DONT want to use a class.

I have tried the follow selectors:

```
table.widget tr:first-child td{
    width:10%;
    border:0;   
}
```

But that selector only will pick the first `td` of the first `tr` no all the `TD's` so I tried

```
table.widget tr td:first-child{
    max-width:10%;
}
```

Of course what I got is the selection of the first child of the `TD`. NOT the `td` itself

it's possible to accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second selector is actually correct:

http://tinker.io/40f64

```
table.widget tr td:first-child {
    background: orange;
}
```

To select the first child of each td, the selector would be like so:

```
table.widget tr td :first-child { /* note the space after the td */
    // styles
}
```

It should be noted, however, that the OP's sample table does not have the `widget` class applied to it.

If your table is expressing a collection of key/value pairs, placing your *label* text within a `th` might be more appropriate:

http://tinker.io/40f64/1

```
table.widget th {
    background: orange;
}

<table class="widget">
  <tr><th>label</th> <td>value</td></tr>
  <tr><th>label</th> <td>value</td></tr>
  <tr><th>label</th> <td>value</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ohhh didn't know about the th before the td.. nice suggestion, thanks is working now...

Comment: what's the difference between the selector without the space and whit space after the td?

Comment: `E:first-child` is just a more specific version of `:first-child`.  Both elements must be the first child, but `E:first-child` specifies that it must be the specific element of E.  So `td:first-child` says *get the td that is the first element of its parent*, while `td :first-child` says *get the first element within the td, no matter what kind it is*.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
table tr td:first-of-type {
background: lemonchiffon;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PRrq5/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table tr td:first-child { color: red; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/74MFH/1/

Comment: He wants all the first `<td>` of each row, not just _the first_ `<td>`